# How to subscribe to an observable once?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, rxjs

My function `access()` needs to subscribe once, each and every call.

In the snippet below, `$valueChanges` emits data to each change made. Calling `access()` without `const $ = ...` and  `$.unsubscribe()`, `$valueChanges` observable emits unnecessary streams of values.

Is there an rxjs operator/function that emits once in subscription inside a function? Even if the function is called multiple times the subscription emits once?

```
access() {
  const $ = $valueChanges.pipe(
    map((res) => 
      ...
    ),
  ).subscribe((res) => {

    ...

    $.unsubscribe();
  });
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  The code you gave will emit once and then complete, without any unsubscribe, unless you send more than one argument to `of()`.  checkout the docs [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/of).  If you have more complex code that is perhaps using a different observable, please update your question.  Please note the 'complete' requirement discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @dmcgrandle Yes, I changed `of()` operator to some `valueChanges` observable which emits values on value change.

Comment: Then change the details of your question to show what you actually did.  What you have given so far does not have the problem you are describing.  Better yet, set up a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) showing the problem in action.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  Is `$valueChanges` a hot observable that is emitting all the time whether subscribed to or not?  If so, when you call `access()` do you want `$` to immediately emit the last value emitted by `$valueChanges` (whenever that was in the past), or do you want to wait for the next value that gets emitted by `$valueChanges`, emit that and then complete?

Comment: and is `$valueChanges` a `BehaviorSubject` (docs [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject))?

Answer (score 4):

You can consider using the `take()` operator, and emit only the first value before completing.

According to the [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take), the `take` operator

```
Emit provided number of values before completing.
```

This is how you can use it:

```
access() {
  valueChanges
    .pipe(
      map((res) => 
        ...
      ),
      take(1),
    ).subscribe((res) => {

      ...

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `shareReply(1)`. Then the original stream will be called only once and its emit will be shared with all subscribers. If the stream emits 2nd time - the update will go to all subscribers too.

```js
access() {
  const $ = $valueChanges.pipe(
    map((res) => 
      ...
    ),
    // take(1), // in case if you need just 1 emit from it.
    shareReply(1), // in case if you don't want to trigger `$valueChanges` on every subscription.
  ).subscribe((res) => {

    ...

    // $.unsubscribe(); // it's useless in case of `take(1)`.
  });
}
```